# A cubic graph with an bridge and the perfect matching

Tags: graph-theory, matching-theory

Given a cubic graph with an bridge. Consider this graph has perfect matchings. How can i prove that every perfect matching will cover the bridge in anyways?
Has anyone an idea? 
Here is an possibe example of the Graph:
[image: Example of a cubic graph]

Comment: Call the graph in the picture $G$, and the bridge $e$. Can you show that $G-e$ does not have a perfect matching? (Hint: a graph needs an even number of vertices to have a perfect matching).

Comment: Since $G-e$ has not an even number of vertices there's no perfect matching. So since there is no possible perfect matching, it has to cover the bridge? Can we say that every connected component of $G-e$ have an odd number of vertices? P.s not for only this example of the cubic graph

Comment: Your second last sentence is the important one. The connected components have odd numbers of vertices, and so they can't have perfect matchings. So your perfect matching needs to use the bridge.

Comment: Thanks for that, but i also need to show that the connected components have odd number of vertices. Unfortunately i dont know how to show it :D Can you help me pls

Comment: Each component of the graph $G-e$ has an odd number of vertices,
since by  the handshaking lemma for the component $G_1$ we get
$2E(G_1)=2+3 (V(G_1)-1)$. So $V(G_1)$ is the odd number.